# Custom route for extension Issue

Tags: routes, plugins, strapi

I got an issue when i trie to acces to a custom route for the extension "users & permissions".

Helped by this topic: [How to add custom routes in users-permissions strapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649504/how-to-add-custom-routes-in-users-permissions-strapi/76092237?noredirect=1#comment134195109_76092237)

I have created my custom route with this file "strap-server.js". he

```
module.exports = (plugin) => {
    plugin.controllers.user.newOneMethod = (ctx) => {
        console.log('test')
    }
    
    plugin.routes['content-api'].routes.push({
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/bob",
        "handler": "user.newOneMethod"
    })

    return plugin
}
```

I see it when I do the command “yarn strapi routes:list”.

Moreover, it appears in the strapi admin panel, I checked the box labeled “newOneMethod”.

But when I try to access it with this URL “http://localhost:1337/api/users-permissions/bob”, it gives me a 404 error : “NotFoundError”.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve my problem?